# ¿en la frase "no ha venido porque"...,entendemos que ha venido, o que no?

Tags: significado-en-contexto

Yo creo que en este dialogo hay un error. Pero mucha gente me dice que es correcto. Me podéis ayudar?

> a-Lola no viene porque está de viaje, ¿no?
>
> b-No, no ha venido porque esté de viaje, sino porque tiene una
> reunión.

En mi opinión en este ejemplo Lola ha venido, aunque por causa distinta a la que sugiere a). Y para que estuviera claro que Lola No ha venido (que es lo que realmente se quiere decir) la redacción tendría que ser:
No, no ha venido, pero no porque esté de viaje sino porque...

Es decir, en mi opinión, si no cambiamos un poco la segunda frase Lola ha ido, porque el "no" solo está negando la causa (no porque esté de viaje) y no está negando al verbo "ha venido". Por lo tanto, tal y como se expresa en el ejemplo inicial, parece que lola ha venido, aunque por motivo diferente al que dijo el interlocutor a). Y eso, obviamente, no es lo que se pretende decir.

¿alguien podria aclarame un poco si tengo o no razon, y por qué?
muy agradecida.

Comment: Se aclara según el contexto, si fuera necesario desambiguar la situacíon.

Answer (score 2):

Coincido en que, para ser correcto, el diálogo:

a-Lola no viene porque está de viaje, ¿no?

b-No, no ha venido porque esté de viaje, sino porque tiene una reunión.

debería modificarse a:

a-Lola no viene porque está de viaje, ¿no?

b-No, no es que no ha/haya venido porque esté de viaje, sino porque tiene una reunión.

El problema radica en la función de "no".

El primer "no" (*no es que ...*) niega toda la oración que sigue: No es cierto que la razón de no haber venido es que esté de viaje.

El segundo "no" niega el verbo "venir" (*no ha venido*).

Comment: muy agradecida a tu rápida respuesta, muy amable.

Answer (score 1):

EXACTO!!! y se precisan los dos "no", verdad? porque si solo ponemos el "no ha venido porque esté de viaje, sino porque..." estaríamos negando SOLO la causa (no porque esté de viaje...), pero no negaríamos que "ha venido".
Y lo que necesitamos es negar las dos cosas: no ha venido y, además, la causa no es porque...sino porque...

Es como digo, verdad?

Answer (score 1):

Coincido en que el diálogo original sugiere que Lola ha venido pero por una razón distinta.

Si queremos establecer que Lola no ha venido del todo, debemos modificar los diálogos. Por ejemplo,

—Lola no viene porque está de viaje, ¿no?
—No, no ha venido. No porque esté de viaje, sino porque tiene una reunión.

La segunda frase se puede simplificar pero hay que tener cuidado porque que la pregunta **Lola no viene porque está de viaje** no explica si viene o no. Si leemos el diálogo fuera de contexto, no podemos estar seguros.

**Ejemplo en que Lola si ha venido**
—Lola ha venido a mi fiesta de cumpleaños
—¡Qué alegría!
—Lola no viene porque está de viaje, ¿no?
—No es porque esté de viaje, sino porque tiene una reunión.

**Ejemplo en que Lola no ha venido**
—Lola no ha venido a mi fiesta de cumpleaños
—¡Es una pena!
—Lola no viene porque está de viaje, ¿no?
—No es porque esté de viaje, sino porque tiene una reunión.

Comment: Sólo por añadir algo más, otra alternativa sería reemplazar el verbo. "No, Lola no ha faltado porque esté de viaje, sino porque tiene una reunión"

Comment: @R18 debrías agregarlo como respuesta agregando una explicación. Esta es una alternativa que no ha sido explorada aún en este hilo.

Comment: @Krauss muchas gracias, muy amable.

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola!

Efectivamente, tal y como comentas (y comentan las diversas respuestas que hay hasta el momento), la oración inicial da a entender que Lola finalmente ha venido.

Como diferentes alternativas para dar a entender que Lola finalmente no ha venido y aclarar el motivo, agergo algunas que han salido de respuestas de compañeros (@Krauss, @Gustavson) añadiendo una última personal que viene dada por un cambio de verbo:

**PREGUNTA**

- Lola no viene porque está de viaje, ¿no?

---

**RESPUESTA**

**OPCIÓN 1**: Doble negación

- No, no es que no haya venido porque esté de viaje, sino porque tiene una reunión.

**OPCIÓN 2**: Negación y aclaración en dos frases distintas

- No, no ha venido. No porque esté de viaje, sino porque tiene una reunión.

**OPCIÓN 3**: Únicamente la explicación

- No es porque esté de viaje, sino porque tiene una reunión

**OPCIÓN 4**: Cambio de verbo

- No, Lola no ha faltado porque esté de viaje, sino porque tiene una reunión.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Eres muy amable.